# Is there a limit for bitcoin withdrawal at Mt.Gox?

Tags: mtgox, reward-schedule, withdrawal

Their page states (https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20490576-Withdrawals-and-Deposits):

> All methods below are subject to a withdrawal limit of 1000 USD per 24hr period and 10000 USD per 30 Day period

They include bitcoin in the list below this statement too. Does that mean they will allow me to withdraw only number of bitcoins that currently has a value of 1000 USD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "They include bitcoin in the list below this statement too. Does that mean they will allow me to withdraw only number of bitcoins that currently has a value of 1000 USD?"

No, it means exactly what it says, that you can only withdraw $1000 a day.

That being said there is an entirely separate limit that they place on bitcoins. On my account under funding options and withdrawals it reads

> - BTC : You can still withdraw up to 100.00000000 BTC provided you have enough on your account (your limit is 100.00000000 BTC per 24 hours )

Answer (score 0):

When you sign up for Mt. Gox, the user agreement says that Mt. Gox can suspend your account at any time for any reason and then will require that you provide verification to regain access to your account.

Anyone accessing their account through Tor will usually trigger this.